# Xcode Accessing the Childnode of a Childnode

Tags: xcode, nodes, children

I added a Childnode(Bg) to the scene and to this Childnode(Bg) i added another Childnode(Rainbow) (so it moves exactly like it's parent node). How i can i access node2?
For example i can't remove Rainbow with [Rainbow removeFromParent]. I can only remove Bg and all of it's children.

Thanks in advance!

Sample Code:

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{
SKNode *Bg = (SKNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"Bg"];
[self addChild: Bg];
[Bg addChild: Rainbow];
}

-(SKSpriteNode *)Bg{
SKSpriteNode *Bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:BgTexture];
Bg.name = @"Bg";
Bg.size = CGSizeMake(600, 330);
Bg.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
Bg.zPosition = -2000;
return Bg;
}

-(SKSpriteNode *) Rainbow{
SKSpriteNode *Rainbow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Rainbow2x.png"];
Rainbow.name = @"Rainbow";
Rainbow.size = CGSizeMake(905/2, 478/2);
Rainbow.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), 70 );
Rainbow.zPosition = -200;
Rainbow.alpha = 0.6;
return Rainbow;
}
```

How can i access the Rainbownode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I needed to make a property of the SKSpriteNode Rainbow!

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) SKSpriteNode *Rainbow;
```